# JPA link between two models from different Rest Services

Tags: java, rest, jpa

How should a link between two Rest Services be done in a JPA model?
Lets say I have a User Service with all user related APIs and a Shopping Cart Service that hols the User ID in a Cart model. The two Rest Services are in two different applications which don't share their database and persistence model.

I thought in two options:

**1 Option - Load User in Service:**
This option would add a transient User in the Cart model that would be loaded by the Cart service.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cart")
public class Cart {

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Transient
    private User user;
}

public class CartService {

    public Cart findById(final Integer id) {
        Cart cart = // Find cart by id in local repository
        loadUser(cart);
        return cart;
    }

    private User loadUser(cart) {
        User user = // Rest API call to get User from Service by ID
        cart.setUser(user);
    }
}
```

**2 Option - Custom annotation to load (lazy if possible) the user:**
This option would provide a custom annotation to load the User. I am not sure yet how to do this, maybe using filters or AOP.
With this option I could make the user ID private and add some manipulation through the user set and get methods.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cart")
public class Cart {

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @UserService(lazy = true)
    @Transient
    private User user;
}
```

The second option would be cleaner, easier to reuse and maintain, but would requere some research on how to build it.

Comment: and why don't you just use aManyToOne (or OneToOne) association between Cart and User?

Comment: I've never used JPA with rest services, but when using multiple tables with one table referring to another with an ID, I use something like `@JoinColumn(name="repo_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "repository_key"))` to annotate a `Repository` field; `Repository` is an entity with an `@Id`-annotated field. In your example, you'd have `user_id` in the Cart table, and the foreign key constraint would be named `user_key` or something.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. They are in different Rest Services. The User Model is in the User Service and is accessible thought the "/user/{id}" endpoint. The Cart Model is in the Shopping Cart Service and has no idea where or how the User is stored.

Comment: You mean the two rest services are in two different **applications** which don't share their database and persistence model? If so, I would do this at the service level, and wouldn't use a transient field. Having a mix of detached, nullable data and managed state in an entity is a nightmare to understand and maintain. Use a dedicated object containing the state of the cart combined with the state of the user.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for your comment. Thats is the case, I added it to the question for clarification. Are you suggesting to add an extra class to hold the state? Wouldn't it add more complexity to manage this state?